# Swift UITextField OneTimeCode Specification

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I try to implement to .oneTimeCode specification to UITextField because of using AutoComplete Verification Code from Messages but it does not work. The Message is not in English also does not contain "Code" String. I think the problem is this. Do you have any idea where is the problem ?

- I didnt implement any delegate to textfield. Also I use system keyboard

Thanks in advance.

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    validationCodeTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Comment: can you show the OP

Comment: What is OP? ...

Comment: The Message is not in English also does not contain "Code" String. - this 
 one

Comment: I dont understand you. What do you want ? . Do you want Message text ?

Comment: Are you asking why your SMS (containing non-english character & without the keyword `code` ) isn't parsed by iOS 12 ?

Comment: No , I ask "Automatic OTP verification in IOS". When the sms comes with security code or etc. at Top keyboard show this code